# Tensorflow: Accumulating gradients of a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

> **TL;DR:** you can just skip to the question in yellow box below.

Suppose I have a **Encoder-Decoder** Neural Network, with weights `W_1` and `W_2` of the encoder and decoder respectively. Let's denote `Z` as the output of the encoder. The network is trained with batch size `n`, and all the gradients will be calculated with respect to the mean loss value over the batch (as shown in image below, the `L_hat` which is the sum of per-sample loss `L`).

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is, in the backward pass, to **manipulate the gradients** of `Z` before passing it further to the encoder's weights `W_1`. Suppose [image: <code>mod_grad</code>] is a somehow modified gradients operator, for which the following holds:

[image]

The described above, in case of a synchronuous pass (first calculate the modified gradients of `Z`, then propagate down to `W_1`) is very easy to implement (the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) multiplication is done using `grad_ys` of [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)):

```py
def modify_grad(grad_z):
    # do some modifications

grad_z = tf.gradients(L_hat, Z)
mod_grad_z = modify_grad(grad_z)
mod_grad_w1 = tf.gradients(Z, W_1, mod_grad_z)
```

> The problem is, **I need to accumulate the gradients** `grad_z` of the tensor `Z` over several batches. As the shape of it is dynamic (with `None` in one of the dimensions, as in the illustration above), I cannot define a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) to store it. Furthermore, the batch size `n` may change during training. How can I store the average of `grad_z` over several batches?

**PS**: I just wanted to combine pareto-optimal training of [`ArXiv:1810.04650`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04650), the asynchronous network training of [`ArXiv:1609.02132`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02132), and batch size scheduling of [`ArXiv:1711.00489`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00489).